# JSP export reponse to Excel file

Tags: java, jsp

```
if (Mode.equalsIgnoreCase("View"))
{  

    try
    {

        DimEN div = new DimEN();
        BcDS divStr = new BcDS();
        if(divisionCode==null || divisionCode.equals(""))
        {
            divisionCode = "All";
        }

        ArrayList divRec = divStr.getLinkBC(divisionCode,divisionCriteria);

        if(outputExcel.equals("true")){
            out.println("outputExcel true");
            response.setContentType("application/excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=DivisionBc.xls");
        }

        if(divRec != null)
        {
        if (divRec.size() > 0)
            {
                Paging = divRec.size(); 
                RecordPerPage=15;

%>

                <br>
                <center>
                <table class="LARGE" width="90%" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=7 class="HEAD" align=center>View - Division - BC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class=LABEL>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class=LABEL colspan=3 align=center>Created</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class=LABEL>Company Code</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>Division Code</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>Business Code</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>Created on</td>
                        <td class=LABEL>Created by</td>
                    </tr>
                    <%@ include file="Include/NavTop.jsp" %>
<%          

                    for (int i=StartIndex; i<LastIndex; i++)
                    //for (int i = 0; i < divRec.size(); i++)
                    {
                        div = (com.gil.hris.DimEN)divRec.get(i);
                        String dispDateCreate = div.getCreationDate();
                        String dispDateValid = div.getValidUpto();
                        String QDateCreate = "";
                        String QDateValid = "";

                        if (dispDateCreate == null)
                        {
                            QDateCreate  = "-";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String yyyyD = dispDateCreate.substring(0,4);
                            String mmD = dispDateCreate.substring(5,7);
                            String ddD = dispDateCreate.substring(8,10);
                            QDateCreate  = ddD+"/"+mmD+"/"+yyyyD;
                        }

                        if (dispDateValid == null)
                        {
                            QDateValid = "-";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String yyyyD = dispDateValid.substring(0,4);
                            String mmD = dispDateValid.substring(5,7);
                            String ddD = dispDateValid.substring(8,10);
                            QDateValid = ddD+"/"+mmD+"/"+yyyyD;
                        }

                        if (i%2==0)
                        {
%>
                            <tr>
                                <td class=QUERY><%=company_code%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY><%=div.getDimCode()%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY><%=div.getBcCode()%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY><%=QDateCreate%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY><%=div.getCreatedByEmp()%></td>
                            </tr>
<%
                        }
                        else
                        {
%>
                            <tr>
                                <td class=QUERY2><%=company_code%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY2><%=div.getDimCode()%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY2><%=div.getBcCode()%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY2><%=QDateCreate%></td>
                                <td class=QUERY2><%=div.getCreatedByEmp()%></td>
                            </tr>
<%
                        }

                    } 
%>
                </table>

                </center>
<%

            }

        }
        else
        {
            mesg = Database.getMessage();
            //mesg="Error - Division Code Not Found.";
%>
            <br>
            <center>
                <table class="small" width="60%">
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="HEAD" align=center>View - Division - BC</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="LABEL" align=center><%= mesg %></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
<%
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
          mesg = "General Error";
    }   
}
```

this is my code but it is not working.
Excel is not generating.

Can Any one help. thanks.
Also I use, following code
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DivisionBc.xls");
Still it doesn't work.

Comment: What library do you use for Excel generation? Where do you generate the Excel document? I only see that you create some HTML.

Comment: You don't get an Excel document by only set the content type to "application/excel" and the Content-Disposition header to a filename with suffix xls. You have to actually generate the file in Excel format and send it back to the browser. But in your JSP you are generation HTML and that is contained in the response. What was your plan to generate the Excel file and send it to the client and where is the corresponding code?